# Excel Macros / VBA - conditionally resizing rows only if wrapped text does not fit

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm currently working on a broader macro to replicate a certain range of rows (essentially one printed sheet) any specified number of times.  The cells appear immediately below the prior (i.e. rows 13:27 are replicated in 28:42, 43:57, etc. up to whatever quantity is specified).  All formulas within the range are dynamic and rely on various references so that the content on each new "page" is different.

Sometimes the content on certain "pages" exceeds the space of the cell.  I'm looking for a way to check every single row after the starting point (say row 13 until whatever the last row with content is after all of the duplications) and to auto-resize the row *only if the row would get larger in the auto-resize*.  I need to maintain a minimum height for each row (50 pixels), so that the macro will only auto-resize the row if the height will increase.

Would anyone know a way to do this efficiently?  I'm still fairly new to VBA, so I'm happy to consider any option/alternative or provide any clarification to help figure this out. Thanks!

Comment: How about to capture the default row height (probably 50) and then for each row height do an autofit. If the autofit height is (significantly?) different from the default height, keep the new height. Otherwise, set it back to the default.

Comment: this is possible, but we need more information. how many columns does a row space? if it's one column how long should the column be? do you want the wrap the text?

Answer (score 0):

As explained by @PeterT in the comments, all you really need to do is try an auto-fit and reject sizes that you don't want.  I typically use this method for columns rather than rows, but the concept is the same.

```
Dim YourRange As Range
'Whatever you're using to obtain a reference to it.

'...

Dim row As Long
For row = 13 To YourRange.Rows.Count
    YourRange.Rows(row).AutoFit
    If YourRange.Rows(row).RowHeight > 50 Then
        YourRange.Rows(row).RowHeight = 50
    End If
Next
```